# Socket.io send messges to only some users in room

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I want to send message in a room using socket.io but i some cases i want to skip some users in room so how can i do that.

Currently i am using below code to send message in group

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    sockets[socket.handshake.query.id]=socket;
    console.log("user_connect",socket.handshake.query );
    if(socket.handshake.query.user_type=="DRIVER"){
        socket.join('orderPool');
    }
    socket.join('USER_'+socket.handshake.query.id);


    socket.on('disconnect', function () {
        delete sockets[socket.handshake.query.id];

        console.log('user disconnected', socket.handshake.query.id);
    });

});

io.sockets.in("ROOMNAME").emit("POOL_EVENT_RECIEVED", data);
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to simultaneously keep another room `"<room name>-selected users"` with only selected users you want to send the messages. Don't add to this room the users you want to skip.

So, when you send messages to this room, users who weren't added to this room won't receive those messages.

Comment: Users are random, i cant decide this which one user can be in group

Comment: You've mentioned in your question that you want to skip some users in the room. Based on what criteria are you making the decision to keep or skip a user?
You can use the same criteria to add and remove users from this new room of selected users.

Comment: i have a booking pool where all users can see all bookings created by riders, if some rider block some driver then driver can not see him bookings . so in this case i want to not show that particular booking to the driver only.

Comment: I understand what you are trying to do here. I will give you an idea on how to proceed. Your application should have some persistent storage like a database where you store all driver and rider ids. When a rider blocks a driver, add this rider's id to the driver's 'blocked by' list.

When this driver connects to the room and wants to view all bookings, then read this driver's 'blocked by' list from database. You now have the list of riders you don't want to display to that driver. Then follow the approach I mentioned in my answer.

Hope this helps!

Comment: That means  now i can only do this in client side ?
is there anyway to do this on server side Like
io.sockets.in("ROOMNAME").emit("POOL_EVENT_RECIEVED", data).except([userid]);

Comment: You can do it on both client-side and server-side. As far as I know, socket.io doesn't have any such 'except' functionality where you can pass in a list of sockets to ignore sending messages to.

Answer (score 0):

sometimes io disconnected and try to reconnect again but I think it's not your problem.

**Note** that you can emit to rooms that exists in **particular namespace**. if you use default namespace `'/'` so try it:

```
io.of('/').in("ROOMNAME").emit("POOL_EVENT_RECIEVED", data);
```

also you can read socket.io emit cheatsheet: https://socket.io/docs/emit-cheatsheet/